# Is it possible to run an Razzle App into another React/Next App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-fullstack

I have an application which runs on

```
localhost:3000
```

which is developed by using "Razzle", and the second application is developed by using "NextJS" which runs on

```
localhost:4000
```

Is it possible to use the "Razzel" application into the Nextjs application without changing the url or the page, both can run in the background but in browser it should like it is the single application.